# ellipses not appearing on text-overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a title:

```
<h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor dumbledore at hogwarts</a></h2>
```

I'm trying to truncate the text on multiple lines if it exceeds the height of `h2`:

```
h2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 52px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

What I'm expecting:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 
dumbledore at...
```

What the result was

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
dumbledore at
```

Why isn't the ellipsis showing?

When I add `white-space: nowrap;` the ellipsis shows but the text of `h2` is now a one-liner instead of occupying the whole height of `h2`.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with some modern css trickery see [jsfidle example](http://jsfiddle.net/USRFobiwan/TTqgR/)

```
body{padding: 4em;}
h3{border:2px solid red;padding:.5em;}

h3 {
display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
display: -webkit-box;
max-width: 400px;
height: calc(26px*1.4*4); /* Fallback for non-webkit */
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 26px;
line-height: 1.4;
-webkit-line-clamp:4;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. </h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) (must read!) suggests you also need `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: but it truncates the text at one line, instead of occupying the height.

Comment: Assumibly, the height of a single line is more than half of the height of the h2. Try setting the `line-height` to 26px (or smaller).

Comment: could you provide a fiddle? I tried playing with it but I can't make it work.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work. It only seems to work (Chrome) is the text flows off the right of the element. So you'll need white-space: `pre` or `nowrap`. With `pre` you can add your own breaks, but it's far from ideal. With the other options it doesn't see, to work.

Comment: do you think this could be achieved via javascript?